# argumentexception was unhandled by user code asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I having trouble with pro asp.net mvc 5 book by Adam Freeman. When I try to start debugging, I catch the error:
    An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not   handled in user code Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'initialcatalog'.But my Web.config not such as in the book.
Screen:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V60zk.jpg

My Web.config code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; InitialCatalog=SportsStore; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
     <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
 </configuration>
```

P.S. Sorry my google translate English.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space in the connection string like so:

```
Initial Catalog=SportsStore;
```

Comment: Can you show the connection string that's in the book?